# AlmaLinux & Apache 2.4 & CVE-2021-42013 (+ other CVEs)

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, cloudlinux

I have a small Apache webserver that was CentOS but is now AlmaLinux 8, and I've been trying to update httpd via dnf to protect against the recently disclosed vulnerabilities: https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html

Numerically, the machine's httpd version number never exceeds **2.4.37**, but I've read elsewhere that RHEL backports CVE fixes to each Apache version that aligns to their OS release.

**Questions**

1. Does AlamLinux do the same thing?
2. How long does it take to actually get the fix to be rolled out?

FYI:

`rpm -q --changelog httpd | grep CVE-2021` returns *no results*.

`httpd -v` returns `Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (AlmaLinux)`

The last CVE I can see on the RHPE is CVE-2021-40438 (https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2021:3754). Does AlmaLinux have anything like this, or does it use the same thing?

~~ Edit ~~

After an update today, `rpm -q --changelog httpd | grep CVE-2021` now returns:

```
Resolves: #2007234 - CVE-2021-40438 httpd:2.4/httpd: mod_proxy: SSRF via
Resolves: #2007646 - CVE-2021-26691 httpd:2.4/httpd: Heap overflow in
```

**FYI:**

CVE-2021-40438: Update 2.4.49 - released: 2021-09-16

CVE-2021-26691: Update 2.4.48 - released: 2021-06-01

Seems that they're cherry picking CVEs to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlmaLinux is s 1:1 binary compatible with RHEL and is downstream from RHEL, so packages that get patched in RHEL will be patched in AlmaLinux also, usually with 1 business day of delay.

https://wiki.almalinux.org/Comparison.html

As you mentioned yourself you can use `rpm -q --changelog PackageName | grep CVE` to see if certain CVE is resolved in a package.

Packages in AlmaLinux come from RHEL, but get some small modifications before being made available in AlmaLinux.

https://wiki.almalinux.org/development/Packaging.html

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't suppose you'd know why an "urgent, patch now" Apache issue wouldn't even have a errata listing with RHEL, would you?

Comment: @Mark if you are referring to CVE-2021-42013 it doesn't seem to affect httpd that ships on RHEL https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2021-42013

Comment: Yes, that was one of the many that I saw on the Apache security page. I went looking for that one specifically and saw a number of them that were important, and didn't look at related minimum versions. But that's good to know :) thank you.